# Adding new Main Menu object to project in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode4, interface-builder, xib, osx-lion

If I delete Main Menu object in MainMenu.xib for whatever reason, is it possible to recreate it?

I have tried to add Menu object, but unfortunately I cannot make it main menu. Meaning, it is there, I can add menu items, but only in one column and I cannot add other Menus - columns. It doesn't appear visually above in the IB window as well....

Anybody knows?

I have Xcode 4.2, Lion 10.7.2 installed.

Answer (score 2):

If found a solution for XCode 6.2:

1. Create a Menu in your MainMenu.xib (or whatever you main xib-file is)
2. Add the default "Application Menu Item" and the "Edit Menu Item" from the object library.
3. Save and close XCode
4. Locate your menu's XIB file in finder and open it with your favorite text editor. It should be XML
5. find the line with "Main Menu". It should look like

```xml
<menu title="Main Menu" id="AYu-sK-qS6">
```

6. Add a `systemMenu="main"` property. Your XML should look like

```xml
<menu title="Main Menu" systemMenu="main" id="AYu-sK-qS6">
```

7. Save the XIB and re-open XCode. Your MenuBar should be back.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure this out either. I deleted the menubar to make a menubar-only app, but it turns out you need to have an (invisible) menubar to use any keyboard shortcuts. So I had to get the menubar back.

I ended up creating a new Xcode project, selecting the (automatically created) menubar there, copying it, and pasting it into my original project.

You have to clean up a few things, but you are able to paste the menubar. That's the only way I could get it back.

NOTE: This may break the connections between the menubar items and their actions. I had to go re-hook-up the Edit > Copy menu item, for example, to the App Delegate's "Copy" action.

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same problem. The solution for me was to tell XCode inside my projects Info.plist which nib file to load as the base nib. So just create a new Menu.xib and change the 'Main nib file base name' property inside the info.plist to the name of your Menu.xib file. So if your Menu.xib files name is 'mainMenu.xib', change 'Main nib file base name' property to 'mainMenu'.